# Parse compatibility with Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, swift, parse-platform, xcode6, facebook-sdk-4.0

I've just downloaded a PARSE Starter Project, as well a the latest Facebook SDK.
I've followed all the steps from Parse and Facebook tutorials on how to get started, and I had to solve a lot of issues linked to the bridging header.

However, now that everything should work fine, I got a problem: *ParseFacebookUtils.Framework* has a

`#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>`

statement.

However, latest Facebook SDKs do not have this framework anymore.
Is there a way I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Parse framework supports both, the 3.x versions of the Facebook SDK and the 4.x versions.

If you chose to use the 4.x versions, use the `ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework` instead of `ParseFacebookUtils.framework` which only supports 3.x of the Facebook SDKs

Comment: Thank you! Where can I find it?

Comment: They should both be part of the archive you download from parse.com. If you used CocoaPods, I think you cann simply add ParseFacebookUtilsV4 as a pod

Comment: Thank you! Looks like it settled that.